# Hive retain Struct notation when coverting into a String

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'll start off with an example to help elucidate my requirements.

I have a table named `schema1.base_tbl` that contain one column named `col_nm_1` and the sample data is below:

```
col_nm_1
abc1234
abc5678
def1234
```

I create another table called `schema1.tbl_dv1` like so:

```
CREATE TABLE schema1.tbl_dv1 row format delimited fields terminated by '|' stored as textfile as 
SELECT
    struct(col_nm_1)
FROM schema1.base_tbl;
```

Table result when querying `select * from schema1.tbl_dv1`

```
c0
{"col1":"abc1234"}
{"col1":"abc5678"}
{"col1":"def1234"}
```

I create another table, this time an external table to get the data from `schema1.tbl_dv1`:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schema1.tbl_dv2
(col_data string)
row format delimited fields terminated by '|' stored as textfile
LOCATION
'maprfs:/data/tbl_dv2';

INSERT INTO schema1.tbl_dv1(col_data) SELECT c0 FROM schema1.tbl_dv1;
```

Table result when querying `select * from schema1.tbl_dv2`

```
col_data
abc1234
abc5678
def1234
```

Which is not my expected result.  The result I want should contain all the mark ups created by Struct data type, i.e. expect result:

```
col_data
{"col1":"abc1234"}
{"col1":"abc5678"}
{"col1":"def1234"}
```

When viewing Hive's part file in the directory it should also look like the results above.

I know this deals with Hive String type vs Hive Struct type, I'm wondering if there is anyway to convert results from querying a Struct type column that contains all its mark up inserted into a String type?

Comment: Also note, essentially I am trying to create JSON data to be stored into a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert struct to Json string with [brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse.git) third-party Hive UDF. It has `to_json` function that can convert any complex type to json string. First, clone and build the jar:

```
git clone https://github.com/klout/brickhouse.git
cd brickhouse
mvn clean package
```

then copy Brickhouse jar to HDFS and add the jar in Hive:

```
add jar hdfs://<your_path>/brickhouse-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```

register `to_json` UDF in Hive

```
create temporary function to_json as 'brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF';
```

Now you can use it, e.g.,

```
hive> select to_json(ARRAY(MAP('a',1), MAP('b',2)));
OK
[{"a":1},{"b":2}]
```

Comment: I have explored and tested that Brickhouse to_json UDF function route and yes the output for the Hive CLI will be in the JSON format, but I believe the backend part file would be in a different format.  I wasn't able to test the "select insert into an external table" with the to_json function to verify the data in the part file as I was faced with an error in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Scouring through Stackoverflow I found that this could be the solution:

```
hive -e "select * from schema1.tbl_dv1" > ~/json_output.txt;
```

it retains the Struct mark ups.